# Strange error by G++

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

I am getting the following error by g++ :

```
wormAlgo.cpp: In function ‘void svm(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&)’:
wormAlgo.cpp:146:8: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
wormAlgo.cpp:146:8: error: expected ‘;’ before numeric constant
```

My code is this :

```
void svm(cv::Mat& trainingData, cv::Mat& trainingClasses, cv::Mat& testData, cv::Mat& testClasses) 
{
    CvSVMParams param = CvSVMParams();

    param.svm_type = CvSVM::C_SVC;
    param.kernel_type = CvSVM::RBF; //CvSVM::RBF, CvSVM::LINEAR ...
    param.degree = 0; // for poly
    param.gamma = 20; // for poly/rbf/sigmoid
    param.coef0 = 0; // for poly/sigmoid
    param.C = 7.0; // for CV_SVM_C_SVC, CV_SVM_EPS_SVR and CV_SVM_NU_SVR
    param.nu = 0.0; // for CV_SVM_NU_SVC, CV_SVM_ONE_CLASS, and CV_SVM_NU_SVR
    param.p = 0.0; // for CV_SVM_EPS_SVR
    param.class_weights = NULL; // for CV_SVM_C_SVC
    param.term_crit.type = CV_TERMCRIT_ITER +CV_TERMCRIT_EPS;
    param.term_crit.max_iter = 1000;
    param.term_crit.epsilon = 1e-6;
```

the code at line 146 is `param.C = 7.0; // for CV_SVM_C_SVC, CV_SVM_EPS_SVR and CV_SVM_NU_SVR`

Can you please help me.

Comment: Could you show the code for the `CvSVMParams` class? At least the declaration of the `CvSVMParams::C` member...

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need the `= CvSVMParams();` part

Comment: @TomasLycken that part comes from opencv. I doubt thre is anything wrong there.

Comment: @RitwikG: Probably not - but it will be much easier for us to find whatever is wrong in your code, if we know the relevant parts of the opencv code =)

Comment: Do you have any defines with `C` as name?

Comment: @RitwikG: Also, as @Andy Prowl pointed out, you should remove `= CvSVMParams()` - what that will do is that it will create an (anonymous) instance using the default constructor, then copy-construct that instance into your `param` variable. If you just do `CvSVMParams param;` you use the default directly to construct `param`, and waste no resources on a dummy object you never use.

Comment: @soon yes. I do . You caught the issue. It works now. Thanks. Could you please add an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @TomasLycken yes, thats a fair point. Thanks.

Comment: @TomasLycken most likely all of the mentioned stuff is already elided by the compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You, probably, have a define for `C`. Look at the code:

```
#define C 42

class Foo
{

};

void f()
{
    Foo f;
    f.C = 7;
}
```

After preprocessing, the line `f.C = 7` will be changed to `f.42 = 7`, so, it will trow an error.

PS: The clangs output looks more pretty

```
/home/soon/Src/C++/main/main.cpp:14:7: error: expected unqualified-id
    f.C = 7;
      ^
/home/soon/Src/C++/main/main.cpp:4:11: note: expanded from macro 'C'
#define C 42
          ^
```

Comment: Recent g++ has roughly the same message as clang here.